# How to reference one object with two interfaces?

Tags: object-oriented-design, coding-standards

Suppose I have two interfaces `I` and `J` that is implemented by `Test` class. Now I need one object of class `Test` that is referenced by I and J both interfaces. I can do it by `singleton` design pattern. But the problem is sometime I won't need a single object in the program. So there is also another approach that I have known.

```
I i = new Test();
i.doSomeThing();
J j = (J) i;
j.print();
```

My question, is there any better way to do this ? 
...UPDATE...

```
public interface I {
void doSomeThing();
}

public interface J {
void print();
}

public class Test implements I, J{
private int a;

@Override
public void doSomeThing() {
    a += 10;
}

@Override
public void print() {
    System.out.println(this.a);
}
}
```

...UPDATE...

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    I i = new Test();
    foo(i);
    J j = (J) i;
    ffoo(j);
}
/**
* This method has business with only the doSomething method that  
* implement the Test class. This method has not nothing with the print
* method that is in the Test class. So it would be well that only pass 
* the I interface to the foo method. 
*/
public static void foo(I i) {
    i.doSomeThing();
}

public static void ffoo(J j) {
    j.print();
}
}
```

Comment: What does Singleton have to do with this?

Comment: Post your interfaces.  You can't do this unless J implement implements I.  J j = (J) i;   That looks like C#.  Did you actually test this?

Comment: @Frisbee I have updated my post. Please take a look.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If I use Singleton then there will be no casting. But the object has a single instance. [This](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/290873/102780) answer is perfect for me. Thanks.

Comment: It that works in your environment the good for you.  Makes no sense to me  to cast  I to J if I does not implement J.  You have an accepted answer.

Comment: @Frisbee I want multiple interfaces point to a single object that has implemented those interfaces.

Comment: You have an accepted answer.  It was just a comment.   Makes no sense to me to cast I to J if I does not implement J.  If that makes sense to you and it works then fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not this?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test i = new Test();
        foo(i);
        ffoo(i);
    }

    public static void foo(I i) {
        i.doSomeThing();
    }

    public static void ffoo(J j) {
        j.print();
    }
}
```

It looks like, in the context of your code, you need a `Test` instance.

You don't need to cast your `Test` to `I` or `J`.  Let polymorphism do its magic for you.

Comment: Thanks. Suppose two interfaces have two different method that has different purpose. Now some of the method only have the business with the `doSomething` method. So they do not care about the other method that is implemented by the other interface. So In my observation, it will be nice if i pass the interface's reference that have only `doSomeThing` method to the target method. please see the update in the post. And sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it many ways.  The approach you took is effective, though I often find my code is more readable if I use some extra characters on the variable name to help identify that there is one object, and I'm merely connecting to two facets of it:

```
I myTestObject_i = new Test(); // creates a test, casts it to I
J myTestObject_j = (J)myTestObject_i;
myTestObject_i.doSomething();
myTestObject_j.print();
```

It's wordy, but I found that in my environment, the words were worth it.

Another approach which we are working with is to use a facade pattern.  In our case, using C++ and many tempates, we are getting a lot of autogeneration.  However, in a pinch, you can write one manually

```
class IJFacade : implements I, implements J
{
    public IJFacade(BaseClass obj)
    {
       mObj = obj;
       mI = (I) obj;
       mJ = (J) obj;
       // error checking
    }

    public BaseClass getUnderlyingObject  { return mObj;      }
    public void doSomething()             { mI.doSomething(); }
    public void print()                   { mJ.print();       }

    private BaseClass mObj;
    private I mI;
    private J mJ;
}

Test testObject = new Test();
IJFacade ij = new IJFacade(testObject); // wrap the object to expose functions
ij.doSomething();
ij.print();
```

The best approach really depends on your application, so I encourage experimenting.